# how to code in Xcode to send different sms messages to different people with single send button click?

Tags: xcode, sms, messageui

I want to know if its possible or not to send different message to different people at a time. Using MFMessageComposeViewController, i can send one message to various people but cant send different messages to different people.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as there are no methods for doing these task within the SDK, However you could use some open source tools such as [Mailcore available on GitHub.](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2)

For example with MailCore you send easily send a email in the background like:

```
CTCoreMessage *msg = [[CTCoreMessage alloc] init];
CTCoreAddress *toAddress = [CTCoreAddress addressWithName:@"Monkey"
                                                    email:@"monkey@monkey.com"];
[msg setTo:[NSSet setWithObject:toAddress]];
[msg setBody:@"This is a test message!"];

NSError *error;
BOOL success = [CTSMTPConnection sendMessage:testMsg 
                                      server:@"mail.test.com"
                                    username:@"test"
                                    password:@"test"
                                        port:587
                              connectionType:CTSMTPConnectionTypeStartTLS
                                     useAuth:YES
                                       error:&error];
```